# How to protect PHP web application sources code

Tags: php, mysql, security, service

We have developed a web application for an office management, the plan is to provide a hosting server.

Therefor due to some circomstences an important part of our targeted portential clients, wouldn't want there work online on the web (even if many security measurment are to be implemented), so we offer a LAN installation for these clients.

This is causing a real headaches for the team, since we don't want someone with enought skills to access our sources code,  since if they do, they can try and find a way to hack our online sytem.

> So, the question is how can we protect our work from beeing accessible, and only allow its execution, obfusticating the PHP code is one way, but its not enough, while seaching I've come accross a way where we can make a Vitrual machine, but this is not the most optmal solution since it will require some hardware configuration (memory and other stuff)

Does anybody know a way out from our misery ? It would be wonderful if its a free solution, but if not, it can be okay with a cheap one :)

Comment: The only people to read the code would be people with access to the server running the website. Are you suggesting this website will be running on a machine that is accessible by others?

Comment: Is your goal to simulate security, for practice?

Comment: @Anthony It's a web application hosted on localhost for some clients and on a web server for others.

Comment: @Chris The goal is to protect the php code to be read/used by other developpers

Comment: I feel that you will run into a problem with inconsistencies by hosting the same content in two different places. Why not have direct the clients to the dedicated web server and not localhost?

Comment: I edited the question, please read it again

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what is the problem with hosting the application online? there are many hosting providers available in market with good security measure and it is affordable. Before complicating the things you should check with some hosting providers. Second thing, let's say you want to run the application offline. In that case, why don't you have the source code directory password protected? so only the users with sufficient privilege can access code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a FAQ here and the received wisdom is that you can't do anything.  This makes sense if you think about it as ultimately there is nothing you can do to stop someone reading what their computer is doing.  If your computer is going to run code, it must be in a computer-acceptable format which means that no matter how you try to hide it, it can be decoded and displayed as in order for your computer to understand it, it must meet certain inviolable standards which are published and well known.

You can make if difficult for people who would not know what to do with the code anyway, but anyone who could use your code will be able to get it if they want to.

Is your stuff so remarkable and innovative that you really think it is worth stealing?
For instance, it took me almost 10 minutes to work out how Google did it's nifty suggest thing and another 20 to replicate it.  By SO standards that is extremely slow.  I use the idea along with almost everyone else but I have never seen their code and it would be boring if they showed it.

Why not just bind users with a non-reverse-engineering contract?  This, after all is how MS protects its IP.  Windows is easy enough to copy if you want to.  MS makes it worth paying for their product by providing updates only to licenced users.  Perhaps you could do the same.

Ask yourself if it is REALLY necessary to have the code hosted locally.  When did the internet last fail you?  3 years ago I experienced a major earthquake.  No power, water or sewage for 2 weeks but the internet both wired and mobile kept working.  My computer didn't as I had no power but 3g was just fine.  The infrastructure is incredibly robust and there is really very little need for local data duplication.  My experience has been that anything that knocks out the internet more than transiently is more than likely going to knock out any local solution too.

Finally, if your clients want a locally hosted solution, ask yourself if they are worth the trouble.  The best way to help them to mature is to let them see what they are missing.

Caveat - I do actually duplicate some data on some local systems but this is a useful feature of backup - I allow clients a view of the backed up data in the event of catastrophic internet failure, but I don't allow them to modify the locally held data as it negates the 'one true record' principle which is why we use the cloud in the first place.